# Calculating Fourier coefficient of a split function with time period $y\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}-1&-T<x\le 0\\ 1&0<x\le T\end{cases}$

Tags: fourier-series, periodic-functions

$$y\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}-1&-T<x\le 0\\ 1&0<x\le T\end{cases}$$
I tried to use definition:
$B_k=\frac{1}{2T}\int _{-T}^{+T}y\left(x\right)e^{-jk\omega _0x}dx\:\:=\frac{1}{2T}\int _{-T}^0\left(-1\right)\cdot e^{-jk\omega _0x}dx\:+\frac{1}{2T}\int _0^T\left(1\right)\cdot e^{-jk\omega _0x}dx\:\:$
We know that $\omega _0=\frac{2\pi }{2T}$ and thus:
$B_k=\frac{1}{jk\pi }\left(1-\left[-1\right]^k\right)$
Which means $B_k$ is $0$ for even and not $0$ for odd.
But according to answers:
They Reached this:
$$B_k{\:=\:\begin{cases}-\frac{2j}{\pi k}&k\:odd\\ 0&k\:even\end{cases}}$$
But no idea how to reach this.
Where is my calculation wrong?

EDIT:
Appearntly I did not know that if I say $k=ODD$, so I can "react" to the k as like a odd one and just multiply by 2 the $B_k$ I got.
That was my mistake, now learned.

Comment: Aren't the two expressions for $B_k$ the same? Note that $1/j = -j$. So everything is fine.

Comment: But you see there is a multipliy by $2$, that is my problem....... If I define $k=2n+1$ I will receive without the multiply by $2$

Comment: This is because $1-(-1)^k = 1- (-1) = 2$ for $k$ odd.

Comment: @DominikS oh, I don't need to define $k=2n+1$ to say it is odd? because currently I don't know if $K$ is odd, but now I see.. I was a little stupid here, at the least, for future I will know it
Thanks!
Should I edit my original comment and say it is solved and just say what was my problem and how solved? I don't know the rules here regarding question solved at comments

Comment: Well, to be rigorous you would say: "If $k$ is odd, it is of the from $k=2n+1$", and you use that in the equations to find out what the implications are.

Comment: If you want you can edit your question, or even answer your own question. :) Otherwise, no further action is needed.

Comment: Got it, will edit my question and say what was my mistake in understand. Thanks!